# How I can solve this difference equation: $(2m+3) w_{m}-(2m+1) w_{m+1}-2m²-4m-1=0$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How I can solve this difference equation:

$$(2m+3) w_{m}-(2m+1) w_{m+1}-2m²-4m-1=0$$

I have no idea to start.

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but Z transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{w_{m+1}}{2m+3}-\frac{w_m}{2m+1}=-\frac{2m^2+4m+1}{(2m+1)(2m+3)}$$
Use partial fractions, and if needed write $v_n=w_n/(2n+1)$

Comment: @ Michael: But I not able to find a particular solution of the inhomegenous equation. Can you elaborate please with your method.

Comment: What do you get for the partial fractions?

Comment: @ Michael: I am not well familiar with method. I am thinking to use the sum of both sides of the equation.

Comment: That is correct, as a lot of the left-hand side will cancel.  If you can find A,B,C so that $A+\frac B{2m+1}+\frac C{2m+3}$ equals the right-hand side, then you also get a lot of cancelling when you sum the right-hand side.

Comment: @ Michael: Thank you very much.